# Does anyone have the privileges to delete someone else's comments?

Tags: discussion, comments, privileges

Is there anyone who has the privilege to delete someone else's comments ?

I think someone has deleted my comments on one of my questions...

Comment: Well, the mods obviously do, else no one I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anyone can flag comments, and diamond moderators can take action if its appropriate (even without a flag). Sometimes they voluntarily clean up if the question and answer are complete and a long comment thread doesn't add anything new.